# JQuery Mobile - Interacting with a Dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I am using JQuery Mobile for an application. While it is a great framework, there are some nuances that I'm learning about. Currently, I have a two page application. When a user navigates to a the second page, I interact with a web service. If the web service returns a success, I load the second page. If the web service returns a failed message, I want to show them a dialog with a prompt. To do that, I'm currently doing the following:

my.js

```
$("#page2").live("pageshow", function () {
  var isGood = getResult();
  if (isGood == false) {
    $.mobile.changePage("/myDialog", { role: "dialog" });
  }
  else {
    // Continue loading page2 related information
  }
});
```

Currently, this logic works almost as I need. The dialog appears. However, when I close it, the "pageshow" event for "page2" fires again. Thus, loading the dialog again. Essentially, I have an infinite loop. I'm not sure how to get around this. It almost like a dialog is loaded into the DOM completely on its own instead of in relation to the page. Because of that, I'm not sure how to respond to dialog events or interact with it. How do I get around this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the best way to do this, but it should work:

```
var dialogShown = false;

$("#page2").live("pageshow", function () {
  if(dialogShown)
    return;
  var isGood = getResult();
  if (isGood == false) {
    $.mobile.changePage("/myDialog", { role: "dialog" });
    dialogShown = true;
  }
  else {
    // Continue loading page2 related information
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I do something very similar, except I'm validating that a user has passed an authentication dialog. The following block of code is the crux of the way I handle this operation:

```
(function(){
  // Bind to jQM's page change event
  $(document).on('pagebeforechange', function(e, data) {
    var loadPage = function(){};

    if (typeof data.toPage !== "string") {
      // Continue with normal jQM operation
      return;
    }

    if (data.toPage.match(/skipCheck=1/)) {
      // We have already performed all of our checks.
      // Send the user on to the desired location.
      return;
    }

    loadPage = function() {
      // The user seems to be authorized right now so let's
      // send him on to his desired location.
      $.mobile.changePage(data.toPage + "?skipCheck=1", data.options);
    };

    if (data.toPage.match(/securedPage/)) {
      e.preventDefault(); // Stop the page load until we know more
      MYAPP.addEvent('isLoggedInComplete', loadPage);

      // This is where you would do something in lieu of the
      // the actual page change event.
    }
  });
}());
```

Note that I have my own object, `MYAPP`, which has its own event system. I use that object's event system to initiate the loading of my second page.

The key to this, and the answer to your question, is the check for the 'skipCheck' query parameter. This parameter is what I am currently using to determine if the page load event should be allowed to complete as normal, or if I should intercept it and do something else.

Another note: this code is from an application that is very early in development. I'm an learning jQM as I work on this application. Thus, this may not be the best way to handle the problem.